# Html e-mail with img tag is not being sent

Tags: php, html

I have a weird problem that when I send an html e-mail without the < img > tag, the e-mail is sent out but with the < img > tag included no e-mail is being sent. The following is the html i am using together with the php code used to send the e-mail:

HTML:

```
<head>
</head>

<body >

<img src="http://www.somesite.com/somefolder/someimage.jpg" />

</body>
</html>
```

PHP CODE:

```
$from = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Some Subject";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Test <'. $from .'>' . "\r\n";

// get emailcontent.html content
$emailcontent = file_get_contents('emailcontent.html');

// send the actual message
$extraHeaders = 'To: ' . $name . ' <'. $to .'>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $emailcontent, $headers . $extraHeaders);
```

Comment: consider using phpMailer or Swiftmailer or similar to send HTML emails, rather than hand-coding the headers in PHP. It makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write content directly in `$emailcontent` without using `file_get_contents`

Also check that the mail is not in `spam or junk folder`, if it is then use 
`return-path` in `headers`

Read also http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to send an email with html then you can try this:/

```
$image= '
<html>
<body>
  <img src="http://www.example.com/image/images.jpg">
</body>
</html>
';
```

and use it with [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
mail("email@domain.com", "$subject", $image, $headers);
```

and your `$headers`sets the content type to `text\html`. Without it, your message is treated as plain text by the receiver.
as:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```